# how can I make a Moveable and resizable canvas draw Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to create a `Canvas` draw (Or maybe another better way of creating this?) that has two separate points in a horizontal line. This is not the problem, but I need the two `endpoints` to move `independently` and also be "resizable" on user touch and drag. I've added a gif to better explain what I need.

[image]

What is the best approach for this? Can it really be done using a canvas drawing? Even better, I just care if the line resizes horizontally, I don't need it to change vertically at all.

I'm not putting here the end goal of this, simply because it's not the point of my question, but if it proves to be necessary I can edit and explain why I need this.

Answer (score 0):

canvas can do any drawing you want, in you case, consider using seekbar or custom it

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand about the seekbar. Can it move from both sides independently? The canvas drawing is not the problem, I just don't know how to move it around. Maybe I could set a clicklistener to them, something like this? I'll probably make them separate, can't figure for the life of me how to make them "joined" like that.